# php bbcode preg match all

Tags: php, bbcode

I am trying to write a function which will be checked the open bbcode tags and the close bbcode tags.

Here is what I have write so far:

```
public function CheckBBCodes($argText)
{   
     $openQuoteTagCounter = preg_match_all('[quote]', $argText, $openQuoteTagCounter);
     $closeQuoteTagCounter = preg_match_all('#\[\/quote\]\s*#', $argText, $closeQuoteTagCounter);
     if($openQuoteTagCounter > $closeQuoteTagCounter)
     {
          echo "There are more open quote tags than close quote tags!";
     }
     if($closeQuoteTagCounter > $openQuoteTagCounter)
     {
          echo "There are more close quote tags than open quote tags!";
     }
}
```

It doesn't work. What am I forgetting?

Comment: `What am I forgetting?` to not re-inwent the wheel, there are at least few dozens of good BBCode parsers for PHP, just use one like this: https://github.com/jbowens/jBBCode it does exactly what you need: http://jbbcode.com/examples#ex2

Comment: At the moment all that's being attempted is to count strings... Why would you use a library for that when you can write a couple of lines of code and be done with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Regex

What stands out most is your regex patterns are incorrect...

This:

```
$openQuoteTagCounter  = preg_match_all('[quote]', $argText, $openQuoteTagCounter);
$closeQuoteTagCounter = preg_match_all('#\[\/quote\]\s*#', $argText, $closeQuoteTagCounter);
```

Should be:

```
$openQuoteTagCounter  = preg_match_all('#\[quote\]#i', $argText, $openQuoteTagCounter);
$closeQuoteTagCounter = preg_match_all('#\[/quote\]#i', $argText, $closeQuoteTagCounter);
```

Which could be further improved:

```
$openQuoteTagCounter  = preg_match_all('#\[quote\]#i', $argText);
$closeQuoteTagCounter = preg_match_all('#\[/quote\]#i', $argText);
```

The `i` is used to make it case insensitive in case you have tags like `[QUOTE]`.

You don't need to escape forward slashes (`/`) because you're using `#` as a delimiter.

You don't need the third argument in the `preg_match_all` because you aren't doing anything with it and you're overwriting it anyway...

### IF(..)

I also suggest that you use the following code structure

```
if(X > Y){
    //Do stuff...
}
else if(Y > X){
    //Do other stuff...
}
else{
    //Do different stuff...
}
```

as opposed to `if(...){...} if(...){...} if(...){...} if(...){...}`